# Office365: Checklist and Workflow

Tags: automation, office365, workflow

We use Office365 and am looking to create a number of equipment inspection checklists where a user would go to a One-Drive link, open a checklist template, use the checklist during equipment inspection and make comments, then upon completion save the document with a machine generated name (apparatus and date-based) to a folder on One-Drive.  In addition, if an item(s) on the checklist is out of spec, a separate email will be sent to a specified email address with info about the defect.

I have looked at MS Forms and it seems very clunky for this application as there are many items on the checklist.  I could create it as an macro-automated Word document, but that seems a bit old-fashioned.

What is the right way to do this?  Are there any examples of this that I could learn from? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should build this as a [standard custom list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-list-in-sharepoint-0d397414-d95f-41eb-addd-5e6eff41b083) in a SharePoint site.  Each of your checklist items becomes a separate field in the list, and thus every New entry in the list is one complete checklist.  I know this seems a little sideways since your checklist items are columns -- but the New Item form and Edit form present the fields for that item in a vertical fashion making it appear more like a check list that the user can interact with.  This then gives you a table listing of everyone's checklist that you could filter and sort and even fire [Power Automate](https://flow.microsoft.com) Flows based on statuses.  Once complete, you can use a Flow to generate a Word document or PDF document and save it in a library or OneDrive.

You can provide users with a hyperlink directly to that list's entry form (e.g. https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/checklistsite/lists/checklist/NewForm.aspx).  If the default entry form does not meet your needs, you can always [customize the list form with PowerApps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form).

Comment: Yes, it does seem a bit sideways and a bit heavy...but I will take a look at it.  Thanks.

Comment: You can do this without touching a single line of code.  The same could not be said for a macro-enabled doc.

Comment: I haven't used Sharepoint in a long time.  I hear it is much better now.  I need to play with it a bit to see what I can accomplish and understand exactly what you're suggesting.  I appreciate the insight.